# unexpected error with overloaded constructor when calling this(...) in Java

Tags: java

I have the error `call to this must be first statement in constructor` when compiling the program below. I think I made it correctly, what is the problem ? I tried two different compilers.

```
class Point{

   int x ;
   int y ;

   
   void Point (int x, int y){
      this.x = x ;
      this.y = y ; 
   }
   
   void Point(int z){
      this(z,z);
   }

}
```

Comment: What is `BasicPoint`?

Comment: Sorry, while simplifying the problem I introduced a second error.

Comment: I edited the question, and the answer given below is correct (I used void where I shouldn't have). Thanks M A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void BasicPoint (int x, int y){` is not a constructor, it's a method whose name is `BasicPoint` and which takes two arguments and has a `void` return type. You want:

```
Point (int x, int y){
   this.x = x ;
   this.y = y ; 
}

Point(int z){
   this(z,z);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question, I meant Point and not BasicPoint. The problem I initially had came from void.